# PHP PDO - dblib MSSQL - using variable in query not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have a reasonably simple query that i want to run with my PDO connection to a remote MSSQL server.

```
SELECT BookingID, DriverID 
FROM dbo.VehicleJobHistory 
WHERE TimeJobRequired > "02/03/2013" AND VehicleID = $vid
```

when i write the query without any variables it works perfectly, but as soon as i try to add a variable to the query i get nothing returned. I think its a type mismatch, but i cant be sure.

If i change $vid to "451" i get the results im looking for.

```
$vid = '451';    
$myServer = "X";
$myUser = "X";
$myPass = "X";
$myDB = "X";

try {
  # MS SQL Server and Sybase with PDO_DBLIB

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$myDB", $myUser, $myPass);

# creating the statement
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT BookingID, DriverID FROM dbo.VehicleJobHistory WHERE TimeJobRequired > "02/03/2013" AND VehicleID = $vid');

# setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

# showing the results
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    echo $row->BookingID . "/";
    echo $row->DriverID  ;
echo "<br>";

}

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

# close the connection
$DBH = null;
echo "connection closed";
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your query is defined in a single-quoted string.  The variable `$vid` doesn't get interpolated in a single quoted string, and is passed as the literal `$vid`, causing a query syntax error since it's unquoted. Reverse the quotes, using double quotes on the outside.

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT BookingID, DriverID FROM dbo.VehicleJobHistory WHERE TimeJobRequired > '02/03/2013' AND VehicleID = $vid");
```

Really though, this should be done with a prepared statement and `bindParam()` for `VehicleID`.

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT BookingID, DriverID FROM dbo.VehicleJobHistory WHERE TimeJobRequired > '02/03/2013' AND VehicleID = :vid");
if ($stmt) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':vid', $vid);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Start reading up on [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). If you are using PDO, you ought to make sure you are getting their security benefits.