# PHP PDO - dblib MSSQL - More complex query issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

my original question outlines my code [PHP PDO - dblib MSSQL - using variable in query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628121/php-pdo-dblib-mssql-using-variable-in-query-not-working)

But now im trying to execute a more complex query. I can get it to work with mssql on the windows server without too much issue, but when i try and copy paste it over to my php page i get nothing.

Im a little confused where i have gone wrong?

```
SELECT 
dbo.VehicleJobHistory.BookingID, dbo.Vehicle.VehicleID, dbo.VehicleJobHistory.DriverID 

FROM 
dbo.Vehicle INNER JOIN dbo.VehicleJobHistory ON dbo.Vehicle.VehicleID = dbo.VehicleJobHistory.VehicleID 

WHERE 
(dbo_VehicleJobHistory.TimeJobRequired BETWEEN $StartTime AND $FinishTime) 
AND (dbo.VehicleJobHistory.VehicleID = $VehicleID)
```

Any guidance here would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your dates. Assuming they're in yyyy-mm-dd format, change the second-to-last line of your query from this:

```
(dbo_VehicleJobHistory.TimeJobRequired BETWEEN $StartTime AND $FinishTime)
```

... to this:

```
(dbo_VehicleJobHistory.TimeJobRequired BETWEEN '$StartTime' AND '$FinishTime')
```

Comment: I should have made it clear in my original question, Ive already tried a few different combinations of that. but thanks!